# expanding variable inside picture environment

Tags: environments

(this version of this question is highly edited based on suggestions)

I thought to quickly create a fax cover sheet last night and, quickly creating one, I ran into a problem I can't figure out so I thought I'd ask around. First, the structure: I have 2 files: one is the style file and the other is the file with the specific fax info. In the style file I've created some variables to hold data that is specified in the info file. Here is the style file:

```
\newcommand{\myfaxdate}[1]{\newcommand{\@myfaxdate}{#1}}
\newcommand\myfaxto[1]{\newcommand{\@myfaxto}{#1}}
\newcommand\myfaxfrom[1]{\newcommand{\@myfaxfrom}{#1}}
\newcommand\myfaxre[1]{\newcommand{\@myfaxre}{#1}}
\newcommand\myfaxnumpages[1]{\newcommand{\@myfaxnumpages}{#1}}
\newcommand\myfaxtelnum[1]{\newcommand{\@myfaxtelnum}{#1}}
\newcommand\myfaxnum[1]{\newcommand{\@myfaxnum}{#1}}
\newcommand\myfaxcomments[1]{\newcommand{\@myfaxcomments}{#1}}

\newsavebox{\faxcover}
\savebox{\faxcover}{%
 \put(0,7){\makebox{\bfseries Date:} \@myfaxdate} 
  \put(0,6){\makebox{\bfseries To:} \@myfaxto}
  \put(0,5){\makebox{\bfseries From:} \@myfaxfrom}
  \put(0,4){\makebox{\bfseries Re:} \@myfaxre}
  \put(0,3){\makebox{\bfseries Comments:} \@myfaxnumpages}
  \put(0,2){\makebox{\bfseries From:} \@myfaxtelnum}
  \put(0,1){\makebox{\bfseries Re:} \@myfaxnum}
  \put(0,0){\makebox{\bfseries Comments:} \@myfaxcomments}
} 

\newcommand{\makefax}{%
 \begin{picture}(10,10)
   \put (0,0){\usebox\faxcover}
 \end{picture}
}
```

Here's the other file (the top-level file)

```
\documentclass[10pt]{report}
\usepackage{./myfax}
\begin{document}

\myfaxdate{09-28-2011}
\myfaxto{Ozymandius, King of Kings}
\myfaxfrom{Bev}
\myfaxre{Two vast and trunkless legs of stone}
\myfaxnumpages{3 counting the cover sheet}
\myfaxtelnum{(516) 676-4099}
\myfaxnum{(800) 123-4567}
\myfaxcomments{blah not blee}

\makefax

\end{document}
```

When I compile, I get an error telling me that `\@myfaxdate` is an undefined control sequence.  I should add that the purpose of dividing into 2 files is because I want to create my own fax style that I may want others in my org to use (maybe). This will simplify it so all they have to know how to do is to fill in some blanks in the main file.

Comment: There _should_ be a problem either inside or outside: `@` is not considered a letter normally by LaTeX. Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: This probably has to deal with a scoping issue; that is, your command `\@myfaxdate` is defined locally and its definition is lost outside of the group it was created in. Perhaps try `\newcommand{\@myfaxdate}{}` outside of any group in your style file, and then use `\newcommand{\myfaxdate}[1]{\renewcommand{\@myfaxdate}{#1}}`? If this does not work, perhaps a little more context by expanding on your "simplified example".

Comment: @AndreyVihrov: except in packages ;-)

Comment: @Andrey - Sorry, I thought that was an MWE. Apparently too much so. I hope this one is clearer.

Comment: @Werner - I think that you're correct. I was messing about last night and saw that if I eliminate the boxes, and just use the picture env it compiles. The trouble is that I want to use the boxes as it makes structuring the page so much easier. Do your comments still apply given the edited version of my question? Thx.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\myfaxdate}[1]{#1}
  \begin{picture}(5,5)
    \put(30,30){Date: \myfaxdate{9-12-2011}}
  \end{picture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: well, it works, but it doesn't conform to my wish to have a style file and a user's main file containing the specific info for that specific fax. Thanks tho...

Answer (score 1):

The box in `\savebox` is constructed at "save" time, not at "use" time. By that time the commands have not yet been defined.

Try not using `\savebox` and `\usebox` at all:

```
\newcommand{\makefax}{%
  \begin{picture}(10,10)
    \put(0,7){\makebox{\bfseries Date:} \@myfaxdate} 
    \put(0,6){\makebox{\bfseries To:} \@myfaxto}
    \put(0,5){\makebox{\bfseries From:} \@myfaxfrom}
    \put(0,4){\makebox{\bfseries Re:} \@myfaxre}
    \put(0,3){\makebox{\bfseries Comments:} \@myfaxnumpages}
    \put(0,2){\makebox{\bfseries From:} \@myfaxtelnum}
    \put(0,1){\makebox{\bfseries Re:} \@myfaxnum}
    \put(0,0){\makebox{\bfseries Comments:} \@myfaxcomments}
 \end{picture}%
}
```

---

A few more suggestions:

- Use `\newcommand{\@someinfo}{}` and `\newcommand{\someinfo}[1]{\renewcommand{\@someinfo}{#1}}`. This will allow you to invoke `\someinfo` any number of times.
- The `\makebox` seems like it could be replaced with just `\textbf`.
- If you use `tabular` or `\parbox` (or nothing at all) instead of `picture`, you need not worry about interline space.

Comment: thanks for you help. As I said in my comments to Werner, I tried your solution last night and it worked fine. The problem is that my actual fax cover is more complicated than my MWE, containing a header for my org and a top block and a bottom block. These 3 blocks I have in 3 boxes. When I constructed the page it's easier for me to move the 3 blocks around as blocks, so I can move the bottom block up as a unit rather than having to give each component of the block a new location individually. In my actual style file the \makefax command has 3 \put statements, one for each block.

Comment: So while your solution works, it's not optimal. The reason I posed this question, really, is not just to get this fax done, it's so that I know how to put variables inside of boxes, as my question states. So I need a solution that solves that problem, not one that sidesteps it.

Comment: @bev: You seem to misunderstand the purpose of `\savebox`. It's not to create a box, it's to typeset text and store the result in a box register. If you say `\usebox{\mybox}` _n_ times, you get _n_ copies of the same, already typeset content. To put content in a box so that you can treat it as a unit use `\parbox` or similar.